# C# space replacement in a certain string

Tags: c#, string, replace

Is it possible to change this:

```
w o r d 1   w o r d 2   w o r d 3   w o r d 4
```

to this:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

?

If I try to replace a single space it removes every single one..

Comment: either use a regular expression or replace three times - replace double space to some made up string, replace single space to an empty string, and replace the made up string to a single space. I would suggest the first option.

Comment: Where are you seeing that text? Are you absolutely sure you are using the correct encoding? For example, reading UTF-16 as ASCII will show nulls between each character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var input = "w o r d 1   w o r d 2   w o r d 3   w o r d 4";
var output = String.Join("", input.Select((x, n) => new { x , n }).Where(xn => xn.n % 2 == 0).Select(xn => xn.x));
```

It gives:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

If you add a NuGet package for "System.Interactive" then you can do this:

```
var output = String.Join("", input.Buffer(2).Select(xs => xs[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have three spaces between words instead of two, it is a little bit trickier than it could be.

The obvious answer is to use two regular expression replaces. First you replace a non-space followed by a space with just the non-space, then you replace one or more spaces with a space.

```
var ans1 = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s, @"(\S)\s", "$1"), @"  +", " ");
```

Perhaps a little bit more obscure, you can use a match evaluator to replace single spaces with nothing and multiple spaces with a single space:

```
var ans2 = Regex.Replace(s, " +", m => m.Dump("m").Length == 1 ? "" : " ");
```

My favorite and completely impractical answer is to use an APL idiom for multiple space compression, here modified to handle your single spaces between letters and based on `IEnumerable<bool>`.

First, you need some extension methods to emulate APL operators over boolean vectors:

```
public static IEnumerable<bool> And(this IEnumerable<bool> a, IEnumerable<bool> b) => a.Zip(b, (ab, bb) => ab && bb);
public static IEnumerable<bool> Or(this IEnumerable<bool> a, IEnumerable<bool> b) => a.Zip(b, (ab, bb) => ab || bb);
public static IEnumerable<bool> Not(this IEnumerable<bool> a) => a.Select(b => !b);

public static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this ICollection<T> src, int drop) => src.Take(src.Count - drop);

public static IEnumerable<T> Leave<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int drop) {
    var esrc = src.GetEnumerator();
    var buf = new Queue<T>();
    while (drop-- > 0)
        if (esrc.MoveNext())
            buf.Enqueue(esrc.Current);
        else
            break;

    while (esrc.MoveNext()) {
        buf.Enqueue(esrc.Current);
        yield return buf.Dequeue();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Rotate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        var esrc = src.GetEnumerator();
        var q = new Queue<T>();

        while (esrc.MoveNext() && num-- > 0)
            q.Enqueue(esrc.Current);

        while (esrc.MoveNext())
            yield return esrc.Current;

        while (q.Count > 0)
            yield return q.Dequeue();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<T> RightShift<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int num) {
    var lead = num;
    while (lead-- > 0)
        yield return default(T);

    foreach (var s in src.Leave(num))
        yield return s;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> LeftShift<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, int num) {
    foreach (var s in src.Skip(num))
        yield return s;

    while (num-- > 0)
        yield return default(T);

}

public static IEnumerable<T> Compress<T>(this IEnumerable<bool> bv, IEnumerable<T> src) {
    var srce = src.GetEnumerator();
    foreach (var b in bv) {
        srce.MoveNext();
        if (b)
            yield return srce.Current;
    }
}
```

Then you just do some boolean algebra on the boolean vectors where the space characters are `true`:

```
var bvIsSpace = s.Select(ch => ch == ' ');
var bvIsNotSpace = bvIsSpace.Not();
var boolVectorInclude = bvIsNotSpace.Or(bvIsSpace.And(bvIsNotSpace.RightShift(1)).And(bvIsSpace.RightShift(1).Or(bvIsSpace.LeftShift(1))));

var ans = new String(boolVectorInclude.Compress(s).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of regular explression and normal string replacing will do:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = "w o r d 1   w o r d 2   w o r d 3   w o r d 4  ";

        Regex re = new Regex("( (?! ))");
        s = re.Replace(s, "").Replace("  ", " ");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The Regex `( (?! ))` means "a space not followed by another space" (negative look ahead) which is replaces by `""` followed by normal replace of `"  "` to `" "`.

Output:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to do it in three steps.

1. Split the string on double spaces
2. In each of the split strings, remove spaces
3. Join all the parts back together with single spaces

I wouldn't use this approach if this is a performance critical operation though, as there's a lot of memory churn involved.

Answer (score 0):

U could also use [remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead of `replace` if your goal is to get wanted output.

```
     string a = "w o r d 1   w o r d 2   w o r d 3   w o r d 4 ";
                for(int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
                {
                    if (a[i] == ' ')
                       a = a.Remove(i, 1);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(a);
```

just loop trough string and remove **1** character by specified index.

otuput: `word1 word2 word3 word4`

Answer (score 0):

Write into new string all non-space chars and only this spaces, which have a space next to.

```
var w = "w o r d 1   w o r d 2   w o r d 3   w o r d 4";
var n = string.Empty;

for (var i = 0; i < w.Length; i++) 
{
    if (w[i] == ' ' && i+1 < w.Length && w[i+1] != ' ')
    { 
        n += ""; 
    }
    else 
    {
        n += w[i];
    }
}
```